# R- State map coming with lot of empty space on the sides

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to color states based on some pre defined rules. The problem is that the map ha a lot of white space in the side and the map itself is getting pixelated on enlarging. Is there a way to remove the white space and just keep the map in the export file.

```
library('maps')
map('state',fill=FALSE,bg='transparent')

map('state',region=c('MICHIGAN','MISSOURI','WISCONSIN','SOUTH CAROLINA','COLORADO','NEW JERSEY','MINNESOTA','OREGON','NEW MEXICO','NEVADA',
                 'NEW HAMPSHIRE','MAINE','RHODE ISLAND','UTAH','MONTANA','VERMONT','IDAHO','ALASKA','DELAWARE',
                 'SOUTH DAKOTA','WYOMING'),
fill=TRUE, col="darkolivegreen4",add=TRUE)

map('state',region=c('TEXAS','CALIFORNIA','OHIO','ILLINOIS','GEORGIA','MASSACHUSETTS','PENNSYLVANIA','INDIANA','NORTH CAROLINA','TENNESSEE',
                 'WASHINGTON','KENTUCKY','MISSISSIPPI','ALABAMA','OKLAHOMA','ARKANSAS','KANSAS','HAWAII','WEST VIRGINIA',
                 'NORTH DAKOTA'),
fill=TRUE, col="khaki1",add=TRUE)

map('state',region=c('FLORIDA','NEW YORK','VIRGINIA','MARYLAND','LOUISIANA','CONNECTICUT','ARIZONA','IOWA','NEBRASKA'),
fill=TRUE, col="salmon2",add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Is the white space on the left-hand side of the map? This might be because you're plotting Hawaii?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem... Are you using RStudio?
For me reloading the maps library worked.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your not using a projection, you should be able to change the margins with `mar` to remove the whitespace.

```
library(maps)
map('state', mar = rep(0, 4))
```

For some reason when one includes a different projection, the margins are lost. I haven't figured out why yet.